# How to animate an indicating arrow below a specific position in a fixed time?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

As you can see, there are 5 buttons over an indicating arrow, the arrow triangle object is separate, and I can move it.

By default the triangle is on button 1

What is the best way to make it like when I tap button 3, it moves there in 0.2 second, just to take 0.2 second whatever number of space it moves, what is the best way to do it?

Do you I need to make interpolation or there is something ready for this?

[image]

Comment: Check out `UIView.animateWithDuration`, you can specify the duration of the animation, so no interpolation is needed, and just set the X coordinate or your `NSLayoutConstraint` of your triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Mr Daniel Nagy said

animateWithDuration did the job, done ! :)

```
   func moveSideBarToXposition(target: Int)
    {
        var convertedXposition = CGFloat(0)

        if(target == 1){convertedXposition = imageViewFacebook.center.x}
        if(target == 2){convertedXposition = imageViewTwitter.center.x}
        if(target == 3){convertedXposition = imageViewSnapChat.center.x}
        if(target == 4){convertedXposition = imageViewInstagram.center.x}
        if(target == 5){convertedXposition = imageViewLinkedIn.center.x}
        if(target == 6){convertedXposition = imageViewPintrest.center.x}

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.05, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone, animations:
        {
            () -> Void in
            self.imageViewHighlightTri.frame = CGRectMake(convertedXposition, self.imageViewHighlightTri.frame.origin.y, self.imageViewHighlightTri.frame.size.width, self.imageViewHighlightTri.frame.size.height)

        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in })
    }
```